# store function in Dart JsFunction and Call it

Tags: javascript, dart

I have stored a function in this way:

```
JsFunction onPauseOriginal;

this.onPauseOriginal = this.mediaManager['onPause'];
```

I try to call it in this way:

```
this.onPauseOriginal.apply([event]);
```

But I catch this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: t1.onPauseOriginal.apply$1 is not a function
```

Why?

Comment: Can you create a https://dartpad.dartlang.org/ that demonstrates the problem? For me it's not clear what you're trying to do. What is `this.mediaManager`?

Comment: This is probably not Angular2 related

Comment: mediaManager is a Js chrome cast receiver object . it contains the function Js on Pause https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/receiver/cast.receiver.MediaManager#onPause

Comment: my first guess is that onPause is null? But look at it in devtools, or provide a Dartpad example. If it is a JsFunction, then apply should work.